DevOps deploying Azure Web Apps to wwwroot/Content/D_C/a/1/s/ in Linux container
I have nearly the most simple Pipeline/Release for a .Net 8 project.
The .zip file has a Content/D_C/a/1/s/ and since it's deploying to a linux container it doesn't attempt to unwrap this.  I tried changing my build host to ubuntu-24.04 but it said that I don't have mono installed.  I think that might be the actual issue I need to solve.  I can't see anywhere I'm targeting .Net Framework in my core app.  All my projects target net8.0 only.  So why would it want mono?  But either way, this should work building with a Windows VM; right?
This somewhat describes my issue:
Azure web app get deployed but wrong content in wwwroot folder

I can reproduce the same issue when using the VSBuild task template default argument.
For example:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'


To remove additional folder path in the zip package, we need to change the VSbuild task argument:
VSbuild Argument sample:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\"

Build Pipeline sample:
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
 

We can use archive files task to zip all output files.
In this case, it will not contains additional folder path in the zip file.
Result:

Then when we deploy the package to Web App, the files will be deployed to wwwroot/ folder.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Deploy Web App

Web packages created via the MSBuild task (with default arguments) have a nested folder structure that can be deployed correctly only by Web Deploy.


That worked for both linux and Windows deployments.
